# How to use windows service created from a separate project

Tags: c#, wsh

Let's say I have an existing Windows form application and I created a new Windows Service project.

The windows form application will stand as the UI of my application and the windows service contains some methods that I wanted to call later.

my question is how can I possibly call the methods from my windows service since it is created from a separate project? What should be the approach?

Let's say the Windows Service contains this:

```
    static Boolean connectionStatus = false;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ....
        //Connect to Server
        //Once connected change the "connectionStatus" to true
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        connectionStatus = false;
    }

    //If I want to check if this Service is Connected into Server, I just call this
    public Boolean isConnected() {
        return connectionStatus;
    }
```

and from the Windows Form Application which is separated project from Windows Service:

```
...
//Let's say I want to show a MessageBox containing if the Service is connected to Server
MyService myservice = new MyService();
MessageBox.Show("Client Status: " + myservice.isConnected());
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to add your Service Project to the Forms application and add reference to it? As here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx

Comment: What kind of method are you calling? Is it WCF? If it is not, what do you mean by calling? Should the other project act as a library? In this case the fact that it is a windows service is irrelevant.

Comment: From my windows service there is a UDP and TCP socket function which will connect into Server. I will have aleast 3 methods  inside my windows service, one of the method is for returning true or false if the client is connected into server.

Comment: I'm talking about calling the method from windows service such as returning true or false if it is connected to server

Comment: @CarsterCors - I already found that link before but I can't make it work, but since you link it to me. I will check it again and try if I can make it work now.

Comment: It's unclear **why** you need a windows **service**. It looks like a communication library is enough. You need a windows service **if** you want to **share** those methods with other applications/servers or running them also when the app/client is **down**: in that case (but it's not what you are describing in this question) consider implementing a **WCF** service.

Comment: I wanted to have a background process which will start during boot and stay running until the machines shutdown so I can determine the connection between my Client and Server application.

Comment: If you want to *track* the connection history, you could write to a db/file and then read it from the UI.

Comment: Yes, but its not just tracking the connection, I need my client to continue listening to the Server message even the main UI is not present(or close).

Comment: Look at my answer, I'm suggesting to write to a local DB (example sqlite) from the service...

Comment: @CarstenCors - Can you please put your comment into Answer? Although I found your given link before and I am not able to make it work, but given me the link again trigger me to try it again and now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the connectionStatus to a file/DB and read it from the UI application if they are in the same machine. Otherwise you should consider implementing a WCF service in the windows service.

### Simple WCF implementation

The main, initial [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx) will guide you through your first implementation.

Based on your question, you'll have a contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IConnService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool IsConnected();
}
```

and its implementation

```
public class ConnService: IConnService
{
    public bool IsConnected()        
   {
        return connectionStatus; //I don't understand if it is a static variable, sorry
    }
}
```

Then you go on with the tutorial, and you build the project and you use the installutil to setup the service (but you know it if you already have a service).
At this point you check the WCF URL service (the `baseAddress` in your `serviceModel` configuration) from a normal internet browser.

Since you'll have also a so called mex endpoint in yuor config, in the response from the internet browser you'll find a simple, trivial C# example of WCF client  :-)
Try it in your application, before the `MessageBox` line.

### Final note

Let me remind you my initial comment anyway.

> It's unclear **why** you need a windows **service**. It looks like a
>   communication library is enough. You need a windows service **if** you
>   want to **share** those methods with other applications/servers or running
>   them also when the app/client is **down**: in that case (but it's not what
>   you are describing in this question) consider implementing a **WCF**
>   service

Comment: Since I am very new in Windows Service, I have no idea on how can I implement the WCF service. Currently the link suggested by CarstenCors is working for me, But I search for WCF service and I am curious which one solution is the best. I wanted to run the service 24/7 and continue listening to server message and process it unless the computer is turn off.

Comment: If you have already solved the issue with CarstenCors suggestion, you have to thank him :-) I'd say it is the "library" approach and it's easier. Implementing a wcf would be a bit more difficult and in this case maybe not needed

Comment: I am asking @CarstenCors to put his/her comment into answer so I can mark it as a correct answer, but It looks like Carsten is not around. Anyway thank you for your consideration :-) I will continue to study about the WCF Service and see if I can implement it in my other project soon. It's good to have an idea given by Stack user, Thank you so much whoever you are.

Comment: I will help you with the wcf. Will edit this answer in a few hours with an example or a link. Thanks

Comment: ooh! That will be really helpful for me. Again thank you so much! :-) I will wait. Thank you!

Comment: @Seynal Done :-) Good luck and just move this into a chat if you have specific questions for me about my answer

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I really appreciated this. I will now check and study this. I seriously Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

@Seynal
I think our time zone are slightly different, but now:

> Have you ever tried to add your Service Project to the Forms
>   application and add reference to it? As here
>   [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx)